# Add a record to the database with relating fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the below model -

[image: EF Model]

I am trying to insert a record in to the database, but I am struggling to select the module when adding a result.

```
    //Create results
    result = new ST_Results();
    result.ST_Modules = //WHAT TO PUT HERE//
    result.User = //WHAT TO PUT HERE// 
    result.DateStarted = DateTime.Now;
    result.Status = 1;

    context.AddToST_Results(result);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

I was expecting to simply enter the ID of the module, same with the User. I can't seem to get it to work.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Change association type to "foreign key association", this should add foreign key property into `ST_Results` (something like `ST_ModulesID`), and initialize this property with module ID.

Comment: Fairly new to EF, how do I change the association type in the designer? I can't find it. Thanks

Comment: Delete association from model, add new one with the same parameters and check "Add foreign key properties..." checkbox in "Add association" dialog.